# How to see message content when simulating in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, veins

When I exchange messages between the modules I can see information regarding the messages but not their contents. For example, I can see that node[0] sent message to rsu [0], name of the message was data and additional info, such as: "id=25 kind=22003, length =166 bytes".

Could anyone please explain to me how to check WSM message content when simulating? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [introductory "TicToc" tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/part3.html) of OMNeT++:

> You can double-click on the messages to open an inspector for them.
>   (You'll either have to temporarily stop the simulation for that, or to
>   be very fast in handling the mouse). The inspector window displays
>   lots of useful information; the message fields can be seen on the
>   Contents page.